# How to install python source code in virtualenv?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I have python source code that I want to make available in a virtualenv (which is used in a Jupyter kernel).  I am thinking about just copying the source code into the virtual environment's /lib directory to make it available.

Is there a better way to do this?  I suppose I could package the source code into its own package but that sounds more involved.